# Condition join in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**(1)** I am trying to TEXTJOIN email addresses in column F, if column B = a specific value. However, it is giving me *all* email addresses, regardless of column B value.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B$4:B$57="owner",F$4:F$57,""))
```

Sample table:[image: 1]

The result I am looking for is:

```
email1@testemail.com,email2@testemail.com
```

The result I am getting is:

```
email1@testemail.com,email2@testemail.com,email3@testemail.com
```

**(2)** If the formula is on a different sheet, I get an #VALUE! error.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(sheet1!B4:B57="owner",sheet1!F4:F57,""))
```

**(3)** I am trying to have the results be de-duped or unique. Is it best just to add `&UNIQUE=[range]` within the array?

I'm sure I'm just missing some detail, but cannot figure it out. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need an `arrayformula()` wrapper:

```
=arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(Sheet1!B4:B57="owner",Sheet1!F4:F57,"")))
```

In **Excel 365** your formula works perfectly the way you wrote it .

Comment: Brilliant. Gary's student has surpassed Gary!

Comment: Actually, one more question: I want to get the unique email addresses in the results. Is there a better way besides adding ```&UNIQUE=[range]```?